# Java null corresponds to Double

Tags: java

I have no idea how to ask this question or what title to use. I hope i do not violate any rules. Anyway, can someone explain to me the following behavior? I have this code:

```
X x = new X();
x.dosmth(null);

static class X{
        void dosmth(Object obj) { System.out.println("X:Object"); }
        void dosmth(Double obj) { System.out.println("X:Double"); }
        void dosmth(int obj) { System.out.println("X:int"); }
        void dosmth(double obj) { System.out.println("X:double"); }
        void dosmth(char obj) { System.out.println("X:char"); }
        void dosmth(byte obj) { System.out.println("X:byte"); }
}
```

What i get is this:

```
X:Double
```

Why it ignores completely the line

```
void dosmth(Object obj) { System.out.println("X:Object"); }
```

And why null corresponds to Double and not Object?

In addition, if i add this line:

```
void dosmth(Integer obj) {System.out.println("X:Integer"); }
```

i get the following error:

```
both method dosmth(java.lang.Integer) and method dosmth(java.lang.Double) match
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When choosing an overloaded method, `null` can correspond to any reference type. When there are two candidates - `Object` and `Double` in your case - the most specific one is chosen - `Double` (`Double` is more specific than `Object` since it's a sub-class of `Object`).

When you introduce `void dosmth(Integer obj)`, there are three candidates - `Object`, `Double` and `Integer` - but since neither `Double` nor `Integer` is more specific than the other - the compiler can't choose between then and you get an error.

As mentioned by  FINDarkside, if you which a specific method to be chosen, you can cast the `null` to the desired type.

For example, this will force the compiler to choose `void dosmth(Object obj)` :

```
x.dosmth((Object)null);
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that you can cast the null to Object if needed.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Double` is more specific than `Object`. From the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.